# Context within context?

Tags: 7

I need 2 context that are identical expect that a single block will not be shown for one. Do I have to create 2 completely separate context (which will be more work to maintain)? Or is there someway to not show a single block within a context based on a new criteria?

For instance my context is page = front page. Im using mobile detect and I need to hide a certain block in this context for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this can be done but its not too hard to have an elegant solution anyway. This is probably pretty obvious to anyone whos used Context for a while but here it is:

Create a front page context that has every block except for the one thats hidden on mobiles. Then add another context that is front page and not mobile devices, and add the block.